# Correct values not getting stored in database when trying to submit form through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload, upload

I have a form that has multiple text fields and 2 file inputs. I am trying to save its value in a database through ajax. Both the files are getting stored properly but the issue is that some of the text values are getting saved as

> [object HTMLInputElement]
>
> [object HTMLCollection]

```
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="data">
  <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">
  <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name">
  <input type="email" name="Email" id="Email">
  <input type="number" name="price" id="price" >
<select  id="Experience" name="Experience" id="Experience">
    <option  >EXPERIENCE</option>
    <option value="1">2</option>
    <option value="2">3</option>
    <option value="3">4</option>
  </select>
<select id="availability" name="availability" >
    <option>Color</option>
    <option value="red">red</option>
    <option value="white">white</option>
  </select>
<input type="file" id="resume" class="resume " name="resume"  >
  <input  type="file" id="file-upload" class="file-upload uploadvisa" name="file-upload" >
  <button type="submit" id="save" class="save-icon-btn">
  <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/supplier/img/Save.png" class="wf-save-undo-icon">
  </button>
</form>
```

AJAX CODE

```
var formData = new FormData();

$f1 = $('#file-upload');
$f2 = $('#resume');

formData.append('file-upload', $f1.get(0).files[0]);
formData.append('resume', $f2.get(0).files[0]);

formData.append('first_name', first_name);
formData.append('last_name', last_name);
formData.append('Email', Email);
formData.append('price', price);
formData.append('availability', availability);

jQuery.ajax(
  {
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "Company/add_workforce_candidate",
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(res) 
      {
        console.log(res);
        //alert(res);
      },
    error: function(errResponse) 
      {
        console.log(errResponse);
      }
  });
```

Comment: <select id="availability" name="availability" id="availability">
firstly remove duplicate id from above line

Comment: use `first_name.value`, that goes for all the `input`s.

Comment: @D.V done, it was a mistake while posting

Comment: @Titus Can you please explain, i didn't understood. Do i need to do it in formData.append

Comment: Yes, I thought that but not sure in that. Anyways great.

Comment: When using `formData.append` you need to provide a key and a value for that key, in this case, the value you're providing is a `Node` an `<input>` element instead of the value of that element.

Comment: @Titus formData.append('first_name', first_name.value); is this format correct?

Comment: Yes and you'll have to do that for all the other `input`s (`Email`, `price`, etc.).

Comment: @Titus I tried but now the values are not getting stored in database

Comment: That is probably because you're creating the `FormData` object before any values are added to the inputs.